# "How do you want to open this file" when open Jupyter Notebook with Anaconda or Prompt

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

When I tried to open it, windows just pop up the regular "i don't know how to open this ext, how do you want to open it" dialog box.
The anaconda prompt gave me url so I can see jupyter, but just no editing functions like run.

[conda prompt initiated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwl3o.jpg)

[Using chrome to open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdtmo.jpg)

[No edit capability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fei5O.jpg)

Comment: post some screenshots for clarity

Comment: Hi I would suggest reading the [guide on how to ask a question properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to open Jupyter Notebook for first time after installation, you will see the How do you want to open this file popup, and this is not an error, because Jupyter Notebook will be opened in a browser and desktop does not know which one to use yet. Choose browser you like from the list and Jupyter will be opened in the selected browser as it should. Later if you want, you can change the default browser.